# Can a C++ text app compiled on OS X 10.8 be expected to work on 10.9 and 10.10?

Tags: macos, c++11, boost, cmake, dylib

**TL;DR**: Text-based C++11/Boost/Openssl application built on OS X 10.8. Should that same compiled binary also work unchanged on 10.9 and 10.10?  Or must I compile it for every release?

---

**Details**:

C++11 application and static library which uses openssl, and boost::regex, boost::asio, and boost::system.  I'm using cmake (since this is a port from Linux + Windows) and everything builds and runs fine on 10.8.2 [Mountain Lion].

But when the application is installed on a *newer* OS X such as 10.9, we're seeing this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTISt16invalid_argument
Referenced from: /usr/bin/myapp
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
in /usr/bin/myapp
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

libboost_regex-mt.dylib did not find `__ZTISt16invalid_argument`.  I'm guessing `std::invalid_argument` should be in libc++, so something has gone wrong.  (Is this part of the libstdc++ versus libc++ problem I keep hearing about?)

This is how I find my library dependencies in cmake:

```
SET ( Boost_DEBUG 0 )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF ) 
SET ( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME  OFF ) # also tried "ON"
FIND_PACKAGE ( Boost    REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex system date_time )
FIND_PACKAGE ( OpenSSL  REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Threads  REQUIRED )
```

These are the flags I set to build:

```
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fpic -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=1000" )
```

When I first run `cmake` it displays the following:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

Comment: It seems a linker error, something you have to take care with `link_directories` and `target_link_libraries` commands (see cmake documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to compile for `OS X 10.7+` you should change:

```
DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=1000
```

to this:

```
DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=1070
```

Otherwise you'll be trying to compile/build for versions of OS X (v10.0+) that are far too ancient to be able to handle your more modern code.

The second thing of concern as you guessed is the `libstdc++` versus `libc++`, which changed in `OS X 10.9+` — `(10.9+ uses libc++)`. Based on that, the compiler you've selected seems to be correct for `10.9`, however, the error is likely an indicator that you need to use `libstdc++`, which would have been used by default on your working `10.8` version.

Try changing:

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

to:

```
-stdlib=libstdc++
```

Comment: Thanks for the MIN_REQUIRED hint.  I wasn't sure how the number worked.  When I change to -stdlib=libstdc++, the compilation immediately fails with "fatal error 'chrono' file not found."  The source line it fails on is:  #include <chrono>.  Is there a trick to using C++11 with libstdc++?

Comment: Sure. It looks like either the compiler is not finding the includes with that error, or `libstdc++` doesn't use `chrono`. Usually CMake is pretty good with figuring out the right compile setting to use; maybe try removing the `std` and `stdlib` and regenerate the makefile to see what it comes up with. When you compiled for `10.8` which version of OS X did you compile it on, and did you use CMake?